# How to read a react file ( ES6 with jsx) with node in order to get the export variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

When I am trying to read the react file that contains the router node crash with error ( i want to build sitemap but even if I just try to console.log the export default variable and I am getting this error maybe needs babel configuration?):

```
    redux\store.js:80 var store = (0, _redux.createStore)(_index2.default,
 defaultState, (0, _redux.compose)((0, _redux.applyMiddleware)
(_reduxThunk2.default), window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() :
 function (f) { ^
```

ReferenceError: window is not defined

store.js code. were the error occured

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  defaultState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);
```

Is it possible to fix that error?

```
react file test.js

require('es6-promise').polyfill();

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store, { history } from './redux/store';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './app';
....

const renderRouter = (<Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history} >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
.....
</Router>
</Prodiver
)

export default renderRouter;
```

sitemap file

```
require('babel-register');

const renderRouter = require('./test').default;
console.log(renderRouter);

/*
const Sitemap = require('react-router-sitemap').default;

(
    new Sitemap(router)
        .build('https://www.omgomg.com')
        .save('./sitemap.xml')
);*/
```

Comment: Read the error message closely: The error originates from `redux/store.js` - in order to receive valid answers you have to share that file here.

Comment: The error also show the code that through the error.
store.js is meant to run on browser (where window is defined) but on serverside is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using webpack you could fix your issue by changing `redux/store.js` to

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  defaultState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    global.devToolsExtension ? global.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);
```

This will work in a Node.js runtime, where [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) is defined, while webpack will [provide it in the browser](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node).

Another solution that is less dependent on your build system is checking if `window` is defined:

```
const HAS_DEVTOOLS = typeof window === 'object' &&
  typeof window.devToolsExtension === 'function';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  defaultState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    HAS_DEVTOOLS ? global.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, for building/developing the project I use webpack.
I want to run a script in order to read router (from app js) and write a sitemap.xml.

Now it pop up me 
TypeError: require.context is not a function

for general.js file which has

export function getImage(imagePath) {
  const context = require.context('../../img/', true);

  return context(imagePath);
}

require.context() exists in webpack but not in Node. Is there any tutorial guide in order to read about how to fix these errors?

Comment: I can't see a `require.context` callsite anywhere in the code you provided. Given this appears to have solved your issue I'd recommend to accept this answer and open new questions for remaining issues (with the relevant information per question)